# Font downloads in latest Chrome, but fails with 401 in Canary

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, nginx

Bootstrap Glyphicon font downloads and displays correctly in Chrome, but fails in Canary. Why?
Here is the headers information :

**On latest Chrome**

Request URL: example com/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Request Method:GET

Status Code:200 OK

Accept-Ranges:bytes

Cache-Control:public, max-age=0

Connection:keep-alive

Content-Length:18028

Content-Type:application/font-woff2

Date:Mon, 17 Aug 2015 09:47:56 GMT

ETag:W/"466c-3862675007"

Last-Modified:Fri, 14 Aug 2015 02:38:31 GMT

Server:nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

X-Powered-By:Express

Request Headers

view source

Accept:*/*

Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch

Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Authorization:Basic ZoJhbmTlZjEwMDplemKxMjM=

Cache-Control:no-cache

Connection:keep-alive

Pragma:no-cache

Referer: example_com/css/styles.css

User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36

**On Canary**

Request URL: example com/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Request Method:GET

Status Code:401 Unauthorized

Response Headers

view source

Connection:keep-alive

Content-Length:605

Content-Type:text/html

Date:Mon, 17 Aug 2015 09:49:10 GMT

Server:nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Login required"

Request Headers

view source

Accept:*/*

Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch

Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Cache-Control:no-cache

Connection:keep-alive

Pragma:no-cache

Referer: example_com/css/styles.css

User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2484.0 Safari/537.36

Comment: Are you logged in to something on Chrome which you're not logged into on Canary? `WWW-Authenticate:Basic realm="Login required"`

Comment: I should be logged-in in both. The http login prompt shows up in both browsers but it seems that in Canary it does not register as being logged in.